# How to find the domain of transformations of random variables?

Tags: statistics

**The Question:**

Assume the discrete random variable $X$ has the pmf $p(x)=\theta (1-\theta)^{x-1}$

Let $Y=X^2$

Calculate $P(Y\geq2)$

**My work:**

$p_Y(y)=P(Y=y)=P(X^2=y)=P(X=\sqrt{y})=p_X(\sqrt{y})= \theta(1-\theta)^{\sqrt{y}-1}$

And $P(Y \geq 2) = 1-P(Y\lt 2)= 1-P(Y=1)$

I am unsure about how correct the last line is, but I believe this is true because the variable is discrete and 1 is the only positive integer less than 2. Is this correct? Also, how can I be sure about the domain of transformations of random variables? I am very unclear on how to do this both for discrete and continuous random variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is true that $P(Y \geq 2)$ is indeed $1 - P(Y = 1)$ (which should be then answered as $1 - \theta$), your pmf in general needs cases:
$$
p_Y(y) = \cases{\theta(1-\theta)^{\sqrt{y}-1} &if $y$ is a perfect square,\\
                0 &otherwise}
$$

As for the domain of transformations, you're right to be cautious. With transformations it's usually easier to compute/work with the CDF of the transformed variable than it is to try to compute the pmf/pdf of the transformed variable directly. For example, you could have approached this problem as:

\begin{align}
P(Y \geq 2) &= P(X^2 \geq 2) \\
 &= P(X \geq \sqrt{2}) + P(X \leq -\sqrt{2}) \\
 &= P(X \geq 2) + 0 &\text{(because $X$ must be a positive integer)}\\
 &= 1 - P(X = 1) \\
 &= 1 - \theta
\end{align}

Comment: Did you just round the $\sqrt{2}$ up? If so, why not round down? Thank you.

Comment: As I alluded to in the text next to that step, I'm using the fact that $X$ must be a positive Integer. This means that $P(X \geq \sqrt{2}) = P(X \geq 2)$, because given that $X$ must be a positive integer, the condition "$X \geq \sqrt{2}$" is the same as the condition "$X \geq 2$". Also, since $X$ is a positive integer, I know that $X \leq \sqrt{2}$ is impossible, so I concluded that $P(X \leq -\sqrt{2})=0$